# Can't find size 57 x 57 in icon composer of Xcode 4.3.1?

Tags: xcode, icons

This is my first time of using icon composer and I'm completely lost. I got the it from Xcode application -> Open Developer Tool.

There are size windows of 256, 48, 32, 24, 16. But I can't find 57, which is what I need for my app! Help please~~~~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

57x57 won't be in Icon Composer. This resolution is for a non retina iPhone icon, and Icon Composer is for making `.ICNS` and `.ICO` files for OS X applications.

Comment: iPhone apps only accept 57x57 or 114x114. Icon Composer can generate png images, but I just find it bizarre that Xcode's built-in Icon Composer is not even able to create an icon to be used in iPhone apps.